"Invalid MultiSpec data" error when running Spotipy in python with threading
I've been working on a spotify downloader for my mother, but it was slow, so I decided to use threading then this issue hit me...
It does all the downloading and stuff then when its time to insert the metadata it just throws this error into the console:
Invalid MultiSpec data: 5
Invalid MultiSpec data: 17
Invalid MultiSpec data: 13
Invalid MultiSpec data: 4
Invalid MultiSpec data: 16
Invalid MultiSpec data: 9
Invalid MultiSpec data: 12
Invalid MultiSpec data: 8
Invalid MultiSpec data: 2
Invalid MultiSpec data: 7
Invalid MultiSpec data: 6
Invalid MultiSpec data: 15
Invalid MultiSpec data: 10
Invalid MultiSpec data: 14
Invalid MultiSpec data: 11
Invalid MultiSpec data: 3
Invalid MultiSpec data: 1

this is my code:
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
import eyed3
import threading
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote
import os
import re


client_credentials_mgmt = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="413cd8a78b454f24aea40811b395a60f",client_secret="cdf657772fb049f9b891bbac789b6963")
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_mgmt)


class track():
    def __init__(self,id,path,is_standalone,count) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.count = count
        self.is_standalone = is_standalone
        self.path = path



    def download_track(self):

        self.return_metadata = spotify.track(track_id=self.id)
        if self.is_standalone: self.audio_filename = f"{self.path}/{str(self.return_metadata["name"]).replace("*","").replace("?","？").replace('"'," ").replace("|","｜").replace("/","_")} - {str(self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["name"]).replace("*","").replace("?","？").replace('"'," ").replace("|","｜").replace("/","_")}.mp3"
        if self.is_standalone == False: self.audio_filename = f"{self.path}/{self.count} {str(self.return_metadata["name"]).replace("*","").replace("?","？").replace('"'," ").replace("|","｜").replace("/","_")} - {str(self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["name"]).replace("*","").replace("?","？").replace('"'," ").replace("|","｜").replace("/","_")}.mp3"


        #retrieve cover art

        urlretrieve(self.return_metadata["album"]["images"][0]["url"],f".\\tmp\\{self.id}.png")

        #search for the music on youtube

        if int(self.return_metadata["album"]["release_date"][0:4]) < 2000:
            search_url = f"https://youtube.com/results?search_query={quote(f"{self.return_metadata["name"]} - {self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["name"]} HQ Remaster")}" 
        else:
            search_url = f"https://youtube.com/results?search_query={quote(f"{self.return_metadata["name"]} - {self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["name"]} Official Audio only")}" 

        self.request_result = urllib.request.urlopen(search_url)
        self.video_url = f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={(re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", self.request_result.read().decode()))[0]}"

        #download frameless video

        self.youtube_object = YouTube(self.video_url,allow_oauth_cache=True,use_oauth=True)
        self.youtube_download = self.youtube_object.streams.filter(abr="160kbps",type="audio",adaptive=True).first().download(filename=f".\\tmp\\{self.id}.mp4")

        #transcode frameless video to mp3
        try:

            self.frameless_mp4 = AudioFileClip(self.youtube_download)
            self.frameless_mp4.write_audiofile(filename=self.audio_filename,logger=None,bitrate="160k")
            self.frameless_mp4.close()
            #add metadata

            self.mp3_file = EasyID3(self.audio_filename)

            self.mp3_file["tracknumber"] = self.count
            self.mp3_file["albumartist"] = self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["name"]
            self.mp3_file["artist"] = self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["name"]
            try: self.genre=str(spotify.artist(self.return_metadata["artists"][0]["id"])["genres"][0]).capitalize()
            except: self.genre=""
            self.mp3_file["genre"] = self.genre
            self.mp3_file["title"] = self.return_metadata["name"]
            self.mp3_file["date"] = self.return_metadata["album"]["release_date"][0:4]
            self.mp3_file["album"] = self.return_metadata["album"]["name"]
            self.mp3_file["encodedby"] = "Soder - version: alpha v0.2"
            self.mp3_file.save()

            with open(f".\\tmp\\{self.id}.png","rb") as f:
                self.track_art = f.read()
                f.close()

            mp3_file = eyed3.load(self.audio_filename)
            mp3_file.tag.images.set(3,self.track_art,"images/jpeg","Cover")
            mp3_file.tag.save()
        except Exception as e: print(e)


def download_track(id,path,is_standalone,count):
    d_track = track(id,path,is_standalone,count)
    d_track.download_track()

def download_selected(treeview,items):
    for item in items:
        #split iid
        data = item.split("-")
        own_id = data[0]
        parent_id = data[1]
        item_type = data[2]

        root_path = ".\\Music"

        if item_type == "tr0" or item_type == "tr1":
            if os.path.exists(f"{root_path}/tracks"):
                pass
            if os.path.exists(f"{root_path}/tracks") == False:
                os.mkdir(f"{root_path}/tracks")

            threading.Thread(target=download_track,args=(own_id,f"{root_path}/tracks",True,"")).start()
        
        if item_type == "pl0":
            playlist_name = spotify.user_playlist(playlist_id=own_id, fields="name",user=None)["name"]
            if os.path.exists(f"{root_path}\\{playlist_name}"):
                pass
            else:
                os.mkdir(f"{root_path}\\{playlist_name}")

            cnt=1
            all_children = treeview.get_children(item)
            for item_code in all_children:
                threading.Thread(target=download_track,args=(item_code[0],f"{root_path}\\{playlist_name}",False,cnt)).start()
                cnt+=1

        if item_type == "al0":
            album_name = spotify.album(own_id)["name"]
            if os.path.exists(f"{root_path}\\{album_name}"):
                pass
            else:
                os.mkdir(f"{root_path}\\{album_name}")

            cnt=1
            all_children = treeview.get_children(item)
            for item_code in all_children:
                threading.Thread(target=download_track,args=(item_code.split("-")[0],f"{root_path}\\{album_name}",False,cnt)).start()
                cnt+=1
        else: print(item_type)

First I thought that the data was overwritten simultaneously, so I made it a class so other instances of the function doesn't write data into others. However this didn't solve it and I have no idea what I did wrong...
